# angular2 how to get data by JSON and render them in html

Tags: json, angular

I trying to render JSON data, 
i do as follows...

```
@Component({
selector:'free-ip',
templateUrl:'./freeip.component.html'
})

export class FreeIpComponent implements OnInit{

getData:string[];

constructor(private http: FreeIpService){}

getFreeIp(){
this.http.getData()
  .subscribe(
    data => this.getData
    );
}

ngOnInit(){
  this.getFreeIp();
}
}
```

My JSON format...

```
 [{"name":"1(К2)","ipange":"85.143.77.64/26","count":14},
 {"name":"1(К2)","ipange":"109.123.184.128/26","count":31},
 {"name":" 7","ipange":"109.123.188.128/25","count":60}]
```

Please help me, how to render data to html?
Thank you.

Comment: JSON already is Object in Javascript. What did you try so far?

Comment: You might be doing your http request wrong. https://angular.io/api/http/Http unless `FreeIpService` allows it. What is the definition of FreeIpService. What are you using for rendering in html?Please show the html as well.

Comment: export class FreeIpService{

  constructor(private http : Http){}

  getData(){
    return this.http.get("/free-ip")
      .map(res=>res.json())
  }
}

Comment: Can you show your template?

Comment: {{ getData[0] }}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:- 
freeIpService.ts file:-

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, URLSearchParams} from '@angular/http';

export class FreeIpService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }
  getFreeIp(){
    this.http.get('src/assets/data/freeId.json').map(response => response.json()
  }
}
```

FreeIpComponent.ts file:-

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FreeIpService } from './freeIpService';

export class FreeIpComponent implements OnInit{

  getData:any;

  constructor(private FreeIpService: FreeIpService){}
  ngOnInit(){
    this.FreeIpService.getFreeIp().subscribe(response => { this.getData = response}, err => console.log(err), ()=> console.log(this.getData));    
}
```

Create service file and paste the service.ts code and create a component and paste component.ts code.  In assets folder create data folder and in data folder create json file freeId.json file and paste json code in this file.

Comment: Yes, thanks. It's work fine and i see my json object in chrome development tools.
But my issue  how render this object in html , for example html table?
How can i get object's value from view?

Comment: Use get data in html like this:- Create a table and heading and get content by looping. Eg:- <table><tr><th>Name</th></tr><tr *ngFor="let data of getData"><td>{{data?.name}}</td></tr></table>.

Answer (score 2):

There is a  simpler way render in HTML using the built-in json pipe:

```
<pre>{{getData | json}}</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should serialize or deserialize your data when it is responsed

The first, this your http service

```
get(uri: string) {
    return this._http.get("your uri", { headers: "your headers"}).map(this.extractData);
}
private extractData(response: Response) {
    let data = response.json();
     return data || {}
}
```

The second, this is function implement in component
    getAll() {

```
this._httpProviderService.get("/api/product_category/GET/categories")
    .subscribe(result => {
      this.productCategories = result;
     });
}
```

And the last, this is html

```
 <tr *ngFor="let item of productCategories;let rowIndex=index">
                <td class="a-center ">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="" name="table_records">
                </td>
                <td class="">{{rowIndex+1}}</td>
                <td class="">{{item.ID}}</td>
                <td class="">{{item.Name}}</td>
                <td class="">{{item.Description}}</td>
                <td class="">{{item.Status}}</td>

 </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of getData">
<td>{{item.name}}</td>
<td>{{item.ipange}}</td>
<td>{{item.count}}></td>
```

this is that i wanted)
thank all for your help